# How to apply custom filters in Yii controllers if there is no separate action for an item creation.

Tags: yii

I am creating a project with Yii Framework.

I have a situation I am not sure about which concerns custom access filters.

I will use a hypothetical example which is similar to what I'm trying to do.

Let's say we have a blog post with the option of submitting comments. Usually the comment form is presented on the same page as a blog post, but depending on the type of the user, the form is either rendered or not (For instance, there is not sense in rendering the comment submission form if we do not allow guest users or another group of users to submit comments).

Now, even if the form isn't rendered, I still suspect that the user can get around it and try to submit a comment anyway (be editing the html of the page, for instance).

So what I have to do is make a server-side validation that makes sure that we have the right kind of user submitting the comment.

And that's where I kinda have doubts.

I know it's a good practice to apply access filters to actions that we do not allow to be executed by certain users, but since there is no separate action for comment submission that renders a separate page, but rather a protected function that handles comment submission and that is called by the view action in the BlogPost controller, I don't know how to go about it.

I take it I can perform a validation if there is a post request related to comment submission when the post view action is called, and throw an exception if the user doesn't verify, but I am not sure it's the best way.

So, the question is: does Yii filtering mechanics apply only on action to action basis or you can apply the different filters to the same action but on different scenarios (such as one when the action has a post request and one when it doesn't).

I'm junior to programming, PHP and Yii so I beg your pardon if I don't make sense sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

In your action that renders both the comments list and form, you could wrap the code that processes comment posts in a call to `checkAccess()`.  For example:

```
// Only allow administrators to create comments.
// This part could be different depending on how you have your roles set up.
if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("admin")) {
    // Something like this, probably...
    $model = new Comment;
    $model->attributes = $_GET['Comment'];
    $model->save();
}

// Do all your other stuff for rendering comments
// ...
```

The tricky part might be figuring out which operations/tasks/roles, to check against.  Here's a tutorial on how to manage basic RBAC. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/328/simple-rbac/

You could also consider installing some kind of rights module to help set up permissions in your project.  I've used this one before http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights

Comment: It's not a problem to prevent the user from posting a comment, what I haven't been able to figure is how to do that using the "checkAccess" along with a custom filter.

Comment: What do you mean by a custom filter?

Comment: Do you mean your not sure how to have the same action handle saving a comment, and filtering a comment list?  That seems different from your original question.